# The bundle version, 1, must be a higher than the previously uploaded version

Tags: ios, app-store

When I try to upload new game build at my new Apple Store account, I was getting this kind of error though I have tried multiple times:

[image]

Let me show you TestFlight section of my account:
[image]

This is new account, I have created and uploading my first game build.

What to do in this situation?

Comment: It is bug with Xcode some times, so better you try to use **Transporter** app https://apps.apple.com/in/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that few failed attempts Apple counted too -- Though uploaded builds not showing in the account but it is not allowing me to upload the same number of build number again. I have tried with Version 1.0(1), Version 1.0(2) and one time Version 1.0(3) get failed because of internet connection lose so at last I got success with Version 1.0(4)

Here is the screenshot of my point:
[image]

I hope this reply become useful to other people.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, you should go to `Runner (Targets) => General Tab` and increase `Version & Build`

For example, if `Version = 1.0.0` you can update it to `Version = 2.0.0`
and if `Build = 1` you can update it to `Build = 2`